# How can I cast javafx.scene.layout.StackPane to javafx.scene.shape.Circle

Tags: javafx

I am trying to cast an object contained in a node of a stackpane, into a circle object, so that I can get the radius of that object.

My application contains in the FXML document an initial track that contains a lane (basically a circle). I now want to add a new lane, for that I have a button that will get the radius of the last element contained in the stack pane that is on the FXML document, and increase the radius of the new circle object, creating a lane around the initial one.

```
 public void addLaneOnClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException
   {
      // This method will make the button add a track

      // Data about coordinates to center objects according with the track //center
      centerXCoordinate = trackCenter.getLayoutX();
      centerYCoordinate = trackCenter.getLayoutY();

      // Data from initial track
      lastElementInTrack = (Circle) track.getChildren().get(track.getChildren().size() - 1);
      lastElementRadius += lastElementInTrack.getRadius() + 22;

      newRadius = lastElementRadius;

      // The new lane
      outerCircle = new Circle(centerXCoordinate, centerYCoordinate,newRadius, Color.TRANSPARENT);
      outerCircle.setStroke(Color.rgb(211, 211, 211));
      outerCircle.setStrokeWidth(25);

      // Placing the circle in the stack
      track.getChildren().add(outerCircle);

   }
```

I was expecting that this would return me the lane. But it gives me a casting error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.layout.StackPane cannot be cast to javafx.scene.shape.Circle
    at application.Controller.addLaneOnClick(Controller.java:61)
```

Comment: Without any info about the scene structure and/or the way you add those circles to the parent we cannot provide any help. The code you've posted is insufficient to identify the issue. [Edit] the question and add the fxml part containing the `track` element and relevant parts of the `initialize` method, if this is where you add circles...

Comment: You're right. I should have done that. I figured out another way to solve it, basically I insert the initial circle that is on the fxml document and push it to a stack and then peek that stack to get what I need.